# How do I tell a background script to wait until page has loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

My current project is a Google Chrome Extension that is supposed to automate a process on a webpage. The way I have made it so far is that the extension opens in a separate tab and you have several separate buttons for individual steps in the process. You open the webpage in another tab and then you click button 1 on the extension tab and wait for it to finish. Then you proceed to click on the next page, wait for it to load and after that on button 2 manually etc...

I am now working on automating the entire process and I am looking up DOM elements on the webpage with JQuery and .click()-ing them to proceed, but my extension script keeps running before the webpage processes and loads, causing the entire process to fail. I realize that I need an asynchronous solution for my problem, but I am unable to find one.

Is there a way for me to check if the page finished loading after the .click() and before continuing the script or a similar way to automate this process?

edit, code for clarification:

in main extension background script:

```
function readPage1 (tabUrl) {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        'url': <tabUrl>
    }, function (tabs) {
        if (tabs.length > 0) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
                'action': 'verifyEmails1'
            }, function (response) {
                <-- logic here -->
            });
        }
    });
}

function readPage2 (tabUrl) {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        'url': <tabUrl>
    }, function (tabs) {
        if (tabs.length > 0) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
                'action': 'verifyEmails2'
            }, function (response) {
                <-- logic here -->
            });
        }
    });
}
```

in the separate script, running on all tabs:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    'use strict';
    if (request.action === 'verifyEmails1') {
        <-- first page reading/populating logic -->
        $('.next a')[0].click();
        sendResponse(response);
    } else if (request.action === 'verifyEmails2') {
        <-- second page reading logic -->
        sendResponse(response);
    }
});
```

Right now, I have two buttons that call `readPage1` and `readPage2` and I wait manually for the second page to finish loading before I press the second button. How do I wait for the tab to load after the `$('.next a')[0].click();` before asynchronously continuing with `readPage2`? (Or, more likely I would compound both responses into one response object and handle it all in `ReadPage1`)

Comment: It depends on what exactly happens on that page after the button is clicked. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The first page reads a list of previously input emails and clicking the button redirects you to a second page that displays a second list of emails that didn't pass the test put by the server. I am supposed to read that list and work with it further in my program (I have already handled reading it from the loaded page).

Comment: If you want to catch the moment that second tab is redirected to a new URL, attach a [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) listener in the background script. If you need more detailed help then add the code you're using to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the built in jQuery methods for specific timing events do not always act as intended, especially when background scripts are contingent upon them.  That said, if it is a specific element that the background script is waiting for to be loaded, the you can use JavaScript to "sniff" for it.  The following example uses teh `setInterval()` JavaScript method to cycle through every 100 milliseconds to check if the heights are equal.  It has an **extra buffer** condition to ensure that the table has been loaded using the `.length` method.  So to answer your question,

> How do I wait for the tab to load after the `$('.next a')[0].click();` before asynchronously continuing with readPage2?

Use `setInterval()` and `.length`. Note that in the example below, if you change the "detector" to look for a class that does not exist on the page, it will not fire and the two table heights with not be equal.

```js
    var makeSameHeight = setInterval(function() {
      var firstTable = $('table#one').height() + "px";
      var secondTable = $('table#two').height() + "px";
      if ((firstTable === secondTable) && $('div.container').length > 0) {
        var doNothing = "";
        clearInterval(makeSameHeight);
      } else {
        $('table#two').css("height", firstTable);
      }
    }, 100);
```

```css
table {
  border-collaspe: collapse;
  border: solid 1px black;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive" id="one">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-sm-4">1</th>
          <th class="col-sm-3">2</th>
          <th class="col-sm-3">3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat="obj in obj">
        <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
          <td>One</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
          <td>Two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
          <td>Three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
          <td>Four</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive" id="two">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-sm-4">1</th>
          <th class="col-sm-3">2</th>
          <th class="col-sm-3">3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat="obj in obj">
        <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
          <td>One</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
          <td>Two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj2 in obj2">
          <td>Three</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about chrome extensions but with jQuery:

```
(function($) {
  winLoaded = false;
  $(window).load(function() {
    winLoaded = true;
  });

  $('.myelement').click(function() {
    if (winLoaded) {
      // do stuff
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Or you could bind the click handlers inside the load function:

```
(function($) {
  winLoaded = false;
  $(window).load(function() {
    winLoaded = true;
    $('.myelement').click(function() {
      // do stuff
    });
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The actual problem is not with jQuery or window.load event per se, but with detecting this event inside the popup/background script of the extension. Most of the questions tagged with `google-chrome-extension` aren't really related to the general js/DOM/jQuery stuff.

Comment: @wOxxOm okay I guessed so. I think I will delete my answer then. Sorry!